# Minimum value of function

Tags: r

How can I find out the minimum value that can be returned by a function with infinite domain in R?

```
f <- function(x) { x^2-1 }
print(minVal(f))   # -1

f <- function(x) { x^2+1 }
print(minVal(f))   # 1
```

So far I've tried optimize, but it requires a finite interval:

```
minVal <- function(f) {
  optimize(f, c(-100, 100))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `nlm` function?

```
nlm(function(x) x^2 -1, p = 1E3)

$minimum
[1] -1

$estimate
[1] -2.499974e-10

$gradient
[1] 9.995338e-07

$code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 1
```

`p` is a starting value for minimization that is required.

Comment: It seems to be working but I don't understand how the p value affects the result.

```
> nlm(function(x) (x-20000)^2 -1, p = 1E3)$minimum
[1] -1
> nlm(function(x) (x-20000)^2 -1, p = 1)$minimum
[1] 224970000
```

Comment: It's just a starting point. The closer `p` is to the actual minimum the quicker the gradient function will work (ie less iterations generally). So if you have an initial idea it would be good to provide that value for efficiency. In the case of these simpler functions it doesn't have a huge impact.

Comment: Ok but if I set the p to 1 the result is 224970000 which is wrong and if I keep increasing it the result is getting closer. The question now is how big or small needs to be the minimum for this to fail.

Comment: Take a look at the output value of `code`. Use the documentation to interpret this value -- it will indicate why the optimization exited. In some cases, with a poor starting value, you may need more iterations `$code == 5`, which can be set by `iterlim`. Generally, you'll want to see an exit code value of 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2):

As well as `nlm`, you could try

```r
optim(fn=function(x) x^2 -1, par = 1, method="BFGS")
```

This happens to work with a starting value of 1 or 1000 (although numerical accuracy can almost never be guaranteed for general nonlinear minimization).

This will work even better if you specify the gradient explicitly:

```r
optim(fn=function(x) x^2 -1, gr=function(x) 2*x, par = 1, method="BFGS")
```

Based on some quick experiment, this seems to give the correct answer for starting values between -10^7 and 10^7.